# WPF command bindings in user controls not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've tried pretty hard to find a solution by myself searching the web and following examples but everything I've tried until now has failed. I know that my poor experience with WPF is making me missing something huge and silly but as a matter of fact I'm stuck.
As written in the object, I have a custom UserControl that contains a `RadioButton`. I want to 'expose' the `Command` of the `RadioButton` outside through a DependencyProperty of my UserControl.
The .xaml of the UserControl (named 'ImageRadioButton') is the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfSinergoHMIControls.Controlli.ImageRadioButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"                           
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

    <UserControl.Resources>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <RadioButton Command="{Binding SomeCommand, ElementName=me}"  Name="button1" Foreground="White">

            </RadioButton>
        </Grid>   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

the dependency property in the UserControl program file is the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeCommandProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register(
   "SomeCommand",
   typeof(ICommand),
   typeof(ImageRadioButton),
   new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public ICommand SomeCommand
{
  get { return (ICommand)GetValue(SomeCommandProperty); }
  set { SetValue(SomeCommandProperty, value); }
}
```

Finally I declare in the application that uses my UserControl an istance:

```
<Controlli:ImageRadioButton x:Name="btnAutomatic" GroupName="MainMenu" SomeCommand="{Binding DataContext.NavigateAutomaticCommand, ElementName=MainViewObj}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="140" Canvas.Left="1373" Canvas.Top="5" Margin="6,0,0,5" IsChecked="True"/>
```

worthless to say that this doesn't work (no command is called). I know that there is something silly that I'm missing but after a lot of trials/searching I still cannot find the solution.
Thanks!

Comment: You should add x:Name="me" on UserControl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference the element `me` in your command binding, but you do not assign that name anywhere, which means that the binding source (your `UserControl`) cannot be found at runtime.

```
Command="{Binding SomeCommand, ElementName=me}"
```

If you set the name on your `UserControl` everything works as expected (at least for me).

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfSinergoHMIControls.Controlli.ImageRadioButton"
             ...
             x:Name="me">
```